# Aggregate $match not working within findOne by request.params.. on populated collection. mongoose nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
   'use strict';

var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    ItemSchema = null;

module.exports = mongoose.model('Item', {
    name:  {type: String, required: true},
    comments: [{type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Comment'}],
    rating : {type: Number}
});

'use strict';

var mongoose = require('mongoose');

module.exports = mongoose.model('Comment', {
    ItemId:   {type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Item'},
    userId:   {type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'User'},
    text:     {type: String, required: true},
    createdAt: {type: Date,  required: true, default: Date.now},
    rating  : {type: Number, required: true},
    votes:     {type: Number, default: 0}
});

var Item = mongoose.model('Item', ItemSchema);
module.exports = Item;
```

schemas are above.. the match is not working how I think it should. Really having a hard time emulating these joins.. I'm just trying to return one item with it's comments and the average rating given for it within the comments..

```
 Item.findOne({_id : request.params.itemId} , 'comments',function(err, item){
                Comment.aggregate([
                    {$match: {_id: {$in: item.comments}}},
                    {$group: {_id: '$itemId', avgRating: {$avg: '$rating'}}}], function(err, result){

                    reply(result);
                });
            });
        }
```

If I take out the match, it returns all items with avgRating... I'm implementing something wrong in the $match.

---

here's what I've tried with removing the findOne:

```
 Comment.aggregate([
    {$match: {itemId : request.params.itemId}},
            {$group: {_id: '$itemId', avgRating: {$avg: '$rating'}}}], function(err, result){

            reply(result);

            console.log('BBBBBB', result);
        });
```

Not sure if this is what you meant by removing the findOne, but this is also not working.. request.params is returning the correct ID. it's definitely a valid field in comments, there is a comment seeded in the DB with this matching ID...

Comment: Are you "sure" that comments is not empty? `console.log(item.comments)`. Also, not that `$in` is an invalid operation here, but considering the "itemId" is a field here then why not just `$match` on that field without wrapping in a `.findOne()`? The operation is essentially redundant.

Comment: the console.log is coming back empty.. without the match though, it's still giviing the proper average, comments for this item are definitely in the db. maybe I'm not referencing / populating it correctly. I'll try without the findOne, matching the itemId by request.params.itemId

Comment: request.params.itemId is a string ... $match is expecting an ObjectId